# Athena Geospatial Queries limitations

Tags: sql, json, parquet, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I came across AWS documentation on Geospatial queries and they mentioned it supports only in two formats **WKT (Well-known Text)** and **JSON-encoded geospatial data**

My aim is to run geospatial queries in **parquet** format, Is this possible to do so? or do it need to use only one of the two data formats?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's real, athena lacks good features present in other engines. But fortunately you can save your data as text / wkt inside a parquet.

Athena allows you to create tables through cte where you can specify the file
type as csv , parquet gzip text